# When use the JPA innerJoin, How can i change 'and' to 'or'?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

When mapping two or more columns in innerjoin there is a map to the conditions and
Can I change or a condition?

Parent table

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
private List<KeyboxDept> keyboxDept;
```

Child table

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "KEY_TARGET_ID", referencedColumnName = "DEPT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false), 
    @JoinColumn(name = "KEY_TARGET_UPPER_ID", referencedColumnName = "DEPT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
private User user;
```

Query is made

```
select
        user0_.user_id as user_id1_3_,
        user0_.dept_id as dept_id2_3_,
        user0_.posi_id as posi_id3_3_ 
    from
        cm_user user0_  
    inner join
        cm_keybox_dept keyboxdept2_ 
            on user0_.dept_id=keyboxdept2_.key_target_id 
            and user0_.dept_id=keyboxdept2_.key_target_upper_id  
    where
        user0_.user_id=? limit ?
```

Can i switch `and -> or` ???

Comment: No because it makes no sense in the context of a N-1 relation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about JPA but In Hibernate Using Criteria we can do this....

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(persistentClass);
criteria.createCriteria("propertyName", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` in entity definition. That means, `The operations that must be cascaded to the target of the association`. So the target (`KeyboxDept` in your code) must exist. If you remove it, means no operations being cascaded, I think the generated sql will have no `inner`.

Answer (score 0):

If your search criteria is not a foreign key matching to the joined table key then you cannot use this syntax because there is obviously an AND relationship between the separate column parts (@JoinColumn elements) of the foreign key. This is why the generated native SQL contains the AND. If you need the OR, you need to initialize that member with a separate JPQL query which contains the OR and you do not need the annotation @ManyToOne.